# "Tube" Arrows in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, visualization

I am looking for a way to draw a few (O(1)) 3D arrows with python, which are "proper 3D", by which I mean something along the lines of what Mathematica yields, i.e. rod of the arrow looks like a tube.

I did not find anything in the matplotlib documentation, but surely there must be a way?

[image: 3D Arrow as generated by mathematica]

Comment: Wow, "surely there must be a way" sounds ambitious. I'd say one would start by defining the circonference of the 2D arrow shape; then producing a  [solid of revolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464982/ploting-solid-of-revolution-in-python-3-matplotlib-maybe) from it.

Answer (score 2):

You may create a solid of revolution from some path defined in 2D to create a 3D arrow. The following code wraps this into a function, which allows to specify some of the arrow parameters. This allows to create the path to be used. This is then revolved about the z axis, creating a 3D arrow. To allow for arbitrary orientations of the arrow in space, one may then rotate the complete arrow about the x axis and then about the z axis (`theta_x`, `theta_z`). Finally the arrow is plotted using a `plot_surface`. Note that the axes into which the arrow is placed should have an equal aspect, such that the arrow is not skewed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def arrow3d(ax, length=1, width=0.05, head=0.2, headwidth=2,
                theta_x=0, theta_z=0, offset=(0,0,0), **kw):
    w = width
    h = head
    hw = headwidth
    theta_x = np.deg2rad(theta_x)
    theta_z = np.deg2rad(theta_z)

    a = [[0,0],[w,0],[w,(1-h)*length],[hw*w,(1-h)*length],[0,length]]
    a = np.array(a)

    r, theta = np.meshgrid(a[:,0], np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,30))
    z = np.tile(a[:,1],r.shape[0]).reshape(r.shape)
    x = r*np.sin(theta)
    y = r*np.cos(theta)

    rot_x = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,np.cos(theta_x),-np.sin(theta_x) ],
                      [0,np.sin(theta_x) ,np.cos(theta_x) ]])
    rot_z = np.array([[np.cos(theta_z),-np.sin(theta_z),0 ],
                      [np.sin(theta_z) ,np.cos(theta_z),0 ],[0,0,1]])

    b1 = np.dot(rot_x, np.c_[x.flatten(),y.flatten(),z.flatten()].T)
    b2 = np.dot(rot_z, b1)
    b2 = b2.T+np.array(offset)
    x = b2[:,0].reshape(r.shape); 
    y = b2[:,1].reshape(r.shape); 
    z = b2[:,2].reshape(r.shape); 
    ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, **kw)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

arrow3d(ax)

arrow3d(ax, length=2, width=0.02, head=0.1, headwidth=1.5, offset=[1,1,0], 
        theta_x=40,  color="crimson")

arrow3d(ax, length=1.4, width=0.03, head=0.15, headwidth=1.8, offset=[1,0.1,0], 
        theta_x=-60, theta_z = 60,  color="limegreen")

ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.set_zlim(0,1)
plt.show()
```

[image]